# Pulling data from an Access subform: Run Time error 438

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I click on my "Calculate Total" button (which worked yesterday), I get

> Run Time Error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method.

The code is on a button click event within a form and references a couple different subforms within that form. I tried rebuilding the code and main form.

```
Private Sub Command91_Click()

Me.Plates = Me.MealPlannerSubformsf!TotalMeals
Me.MealSubtotal = Me.Plates * Me.MealRate
Me.Sleeps = Me.LodgingDetailsSubformsf!TotSleepers
Me.LodgingSubtotal = Me.Sleeps * Me.LodgingRate
Me.ExpectedTotal = Me.MealSubtotal + Me.LodgingSubtotal + Me.ReservationFee

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You must address the controls via the subforms' *Form* property:

```vb
Private Sub Command91_Click()

Me.Plates = Me.MealPlannerSubformsf.Form!TotalMeals
Me.MealSubtotal = Me.Plates * Me.MealRate
Me.Sleeps = Me.LodgingDetailsSubformsf.Form!TotSleepers
Me.LodgingSubtotal = Me.Sleeps * Me.LodgingRate
Me.ExpectedTotal = Me.MealSubtotal + Me.LodgingSubtotal + Me.ReservationFee

End Sub
```